# How do I make my 2d game fit screen size in arcade library

Tags: python, python-3.6, responsive, 2d-games, arcade

actually I'm trying to code my first 2d game with python, using arcade library. I want to know if there's a way to make the game fit any screen size without manual adjustment of the width and height:

```
import arcade

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
```

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1. Use full screen mode

Launch you `arcade` app with `fullscreen=True` flag:

```
window = arcade.Window(fullscreen=True)
```

Detailed example [here](https://arcade.academy/examples/full_screen_example.html).

## Option 2. Get display size

Use `get_display_size` function to get screen resolution:

```
width, height = arcade.window_commands.get_display_size()
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work for me, and I use views not window

Comment: the screen doesn't fit to my monitor size, just keep the values that I already set it to width and height